# Upload de Ficheiros

Tags: php, html, arquivo, upload, file-upload

Eu sou novo em php e base de dados e nunca fiz um upload de ficheiros. Já tive a ler e aconselham só a guardar o caminho de um  ficheiro na base de dados e não o ficheiro em si. Aconselharam-me a ver no Portugal-a-Programar e no PHP mas eu não percebi como o upload funcionava mas testei na mesma os códigos e deram-me erro.
Alguém me pode ajudar com o upload de ficheiros?

Comment: Mostra o código que usaste. É mais fácil ajudar. Já agora tudo depende para que fim é e qual a extensão dos ficheiros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trabalhando com PHP puro (sem framework).

1º há duas observações:

1. No PHP com configuração padrão o limite de uploads é de 2Mb então, teste com arquivos menores.
2. Em alguns servidores para você poder salvar um arquivo em uma pasta você precisa de permissão de usuário (também conhecido como CHMOD), é raro precisar configurar isso, mas se por obra divina o seu arquivo não estiver indo pra pasta que você definiu, tente “dar um CHMOD 777” na pasta de destino.

Formulário HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="recebe_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Arquivo</label>
  <input type="file" name="arquivo" />

  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php
// Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
$_UP['pasta'] = 'uploads/';

// Tamanho máximo do arquivo (em Bytes)
$_UP['tamanho'] = 1024 * 1024 * 2; // 2Mb

// Array com as extensões permitidas
$_UP['extensoes'] = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif');

// Renomeia o arquivo? (Se true, o arquivo será salvo como .jpg e um nome único)
$_UP['renomeia'] = false;

// Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
$_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
$_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite do PHP';
$_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especifiado no HTML';
$_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
$_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';

// Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Se sim, exibe a mensagem do erro
if ($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0) {
  die("Não foi possível fazer o upload, erro:" . $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
  exit; // Para a execução do script
}

// Caso script chegue a esse ponto, não houve erro com o upload e o PHP pode continuar

// Faz a verificação da extensão do arquivo
$extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arquivo']['name'])));
if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
  echo "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, png ou gif";
  exit;
}

// Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['arquivo']['size']) {
  echo "O arquivo enviado é muito grande, envie arquivos de até 2Mb.";
  exit;
}

// O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar movê-lo para a pasta

// Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {
  // Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão .jpg
  $nome_final = md5(time()).'.jpg';
} else {
  // Mantém o nome original do arquivo
  $nome_final = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
}

// Depois verifica se é possível mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final)) {
  // Upload efetuado com sucesso, exibe uma mensagem e um link para o arquivo
  echo "Upload efetuado com sucesso!";
  echo '<a href="' . $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final . '">Clique aqui para acessar o arquivo</a>';
} else {
  // Não foi possível fazer o upload, provavelmente a pasta está incorreta
  echo "Não foi possível enviar o arquivo, tente novamente";
}
```

Fonte: [Blog Thiago Belem](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/upload-de-arquivos-com-php/)